# Should questions asking for similar music be canonical?

Tags: discussion, community-wiki, recommendations

The question https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/615/pieces-on-the-same-level-as-sarabande-in-d-minor is asking for

> other classical and famous pieces are on par with this one, so I will know what to learn to play next

and further specifies to

> give me a rough indication of the difficulty of the piece i.e what grade piano it is considered

I'm afraid this will result into a lot of questions of the type "Can you recommend similar music for X?". However, we aren't building a recommendation community as far as I understand...

I think the intent can be saved though, by [creating a wiki](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/01/the-wikipedia-of-long-tail-programming-questions/) of a list of learning music of different difficulties.

What do you think?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think this solves the problem of the questions being too subjective.  Unless we created a wiki for each music grading system and limited it to songs that have been officially graded -- essentially duplicating each system's list -- you'd have people arguing over which song belongs where.  Making it a wiki would only lower the bar for edits and make it easy for people to have edit wars.

I'd prefer people go on chat and ask for song recommendations, or something like that.  "Related pieces", whether by difficulty or style/etc., are still shopping recommendations.  On the other hand, as decribed in [one of Jeff Atwood's blog posts](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/11/qa-is-hard-lets-go-shopping/), I think questions that ask how songs are graded would be fine.  I think we have such a question, actually.

Comment: Thanks for thinking this through, `you'd have people arguing over which song belongs where` is indeed a problem I didn't foresee which indeed leads into argumentative community wikis because of it's subjectivity. And indeed, we have to watch out for song recommendations...

Comment: the last two weeks may be too short but I notice that the Music.SE community is rather helpful, quiet (a bit too much?) and not quick to launch flame wars. Several questions I have voted to close have not degenerated as they could have and resulted in interesting considerations.

Comment: @ogerard I don't particularly disagree, but I think the logic still holds. We don't want to give troublemakers that might come along a foothold, either.

Comment: where can I find these lists of "songs that have been officially graded"?

Comment: @idober I've personally used books of graded songs from the [RCM](http://www.rcmexaminations.org/acadinfo/syllabi.htm).

Answer (score 1):

I concur with this. A single community wiki "question" for such topics (maybe one per instrument/musical style?) would work well. These questions are naturally going to crop up quite often, and having answers in one place works well here, I think.